# Rails Simple Form - Error in dropdown input when selecting prompt message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, simple-form

I am using Rails 4 and Simple Form to create a form where I ask users for a bunch of data. I am including a dropdown selector to a model association in the following way:

```
<%= f.association :location, collection: Location.order("LOWER(name)").all, required: true, include_blank: false, prompt: "Choose location..." %>
```

However, I get a `undefined method 'name' for nil:NilClass` error when the user doesn't actively choose anything and leaves the default prompt message selected in the dropdown.

How can I make the app send the user back to the form and highlight that he needs to choose a location in the dropdown? Just like it happens when you have a required input field and no data is provided...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the `required: true` in your form doesn't actually make the :location a required attribute on your model.

You need to add the following to your model:

```
validates :location, presence: true
```